# How to run virtual hosts under a separate uid and gid beside using mpm_itk?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm running a server where I have multiple websites, so I want to separate users with anything beside mpm_itk.

From virtual host:

```
<IfModule mpm_itk_module>
AssignUserId user1 user1
</IfModule>
```

I'm running `Apache/2.4.29`.

I want to find something that supports http2, since mpm_itk doesn't support h2:

> Starting from Apache 2.4.27, the Apache MPM (Multi-Processing Module)
>   prefork no longer supports HTTP/2. This will be indicated in your
>   Apache error log as follows: AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is
>   not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are
>   processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and
>   the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory
>   warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol
>   will be inactive.

All of my users run only PHP and since there is no CGI scripts, what is the best way to separate users uid and gid?